# Android support v7 SpinnerICS outside of ActionBar

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, android-spinner, android-support-library

I converted some code from ActionBarSherlock to ActionBar Compat using android support v7 appcompat library.

My ActionBar code is working fine.  But I also had some ActionBarSherlock IcsSpinners outside of ActionBar in my fragment and I wanted those spinners to be the same ICS style as before with ActionBarSherlock. So I copied the internal support v7 library SpinnerICS files out of the support library since they are private and we can not use them directly and put them into my own tree.

But when I convert these IcsSpinners to SpinnerICS they no longer work as they did under ActionBarSherlock.  I see a spinner label next to the first item in the list but the little spinner triangle does not appear and pressing the item does not trigger the listener as I've tested with logging.

Here's where I copied the SpinnerICS files in my project(you may have to adjust R. package):

```
$ ls -1 widget/
AbsSpinnerICS.java
AdapterViewICS.java
ListPopupWindow.java
SpinnerICS.java
```

Here's what the fragment code looks like:

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

    View view;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            ...
            SpinnerICS spinner = (SpinnerICS) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

            spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener( new AdapterViewICS.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterViewICS<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {

                            if (pos > 0) { var = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(pos); }  
                            else         { var = null; }
                            Log.v(TAG, String.format("Fragment1: onItemSelected: pos: %d var: %s", pos, var));
                    }

                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterViewICS<?> parent) {
                    }
            });
            ...
            return view;
    }

onActivityCreated(...) {
    ...
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter( getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list );
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    ...
}
```

Has anyone got these SpinnerICS widgets working outside of ActionBar?